# Control-Flow in User-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created this funcion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_Emp_NumEmp
(@NumDe NUMERIC(3))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (
        SELECT
            td.NumDe, NumEm, Nombre
        FROM
            TDepto td INNER JOIN Temple tem ON (td.NumDe = tem.NumDe)
        WHERE
            td.NumDe = @NumDe
    );
```

The problem I have is that I do not find any method to perform flow control within it, and I have not found any reference. I mean, what I'm trying to do is that when invoking this function, if the introduced parameter does not match any value, it shows a personalized message.

Comment: Nope - that isn't how you do things in a UDF or in tsql generally. "Show a message" is something that the executor of tsql does based on certain conditions. If there is no match, your UDF returns an empty resultset and it is the responsibility of the consumer of this resultset to respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most of the programming languages out there SQL Server functions also have a pre-defined signature (Number of Parameters, type of parameters , return type etc).

If you want an object which decides the control of flow, then you should be looking into Stored Procedures and not functions.

The function you have created is an `Inline Table valued function` it is not flexible at all in terms of what can you do inside an Inline Table valued function, it will always return a table, there can be only a single Select statement inside an `Inline Table valued function` etc etc.

If you are looking for a more flexible type of the function then maybe look into `Multi Statement Table valued Functions`, in those functions you can have more complex logic inside your function and you can do a lot more. However, it is still a function and the `Function Signature` rules apply, hence the function can only return a specific type of object which will be a table in case of a `Multi Statement Table valued Function`.

Like I mentioned before if you are looking for more flexibility in your object and trying to control execution flow inside that object `Stored Procedures` are the way to go. There depending on what parameter values are passed you can call different functions and do different things etc.

Comment: Thank you, I think you have led me to the right path. I want to do it with an "if", so if the introduced parameter does not return results, the function make a "select" with the text that i indicate, and if it finds something, perform the search according to the code that you attach before.